# Not initializing a property of a class which is an NSMutableArray misbehaves?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties, nsmutablearray

I defined an NSMutableArray property for a class as follows:

`@interface Simul : NSObject`

`@property NSMutableArray * varibs;`

`@end`

`@implementation Simul`

`@synthesize varibs;`

```
-(id) init{

self=[super init];

if (self) {
   NSLog(@"I am initiated"); 
}
return self;
}
```

Now, in the main function the following proceeds and prints:

**2015-01-18 23:27:06.534 calculate_x[4881:189850] 0.0000**

**Program ended with exit code: 0**

But, we do not have an object with index=2 in the NSMutableArray variable varibs.

What is happening here?
Why there is no runtime error for the non existing object specified by index 2?

Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {`
@autoreleasepool {

    Simul * mySimul = [[Simul alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%.4f", [[mySimul.varibs objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]);

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialised `varibs`, so it is `nil`.  In Objective-c sending any message to `nil` returns `nil` - so

```
[[mySimul.varibs objectAtIndex:2] floatValue])
```

is really saying

```
 [[nil objectAtIndex:2] floatvalue]
```

or

```
 [nil floatvalue]
```

which returns `nil`, which is 0 and 0 as a float is 0.0 given your format

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. After initiating the NSMutableArray everything works fine.
But, the point is [[mySimul.varibs objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] prints a valid floating number 0.0 which is not nil. If sending a message to nil will return nil, then we should not get 0.0. We should get nil or a runtime error of some sort. Any idea?

Comment: Well, nil is just 0, so 0 as a float is 0.0. Unlike Swift, Objective-C doesn't check types at runtime. You can debate whether this is better or worse than a runtime exception, but it is the design decision that was made with Objecive-C.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I shall be very careful with this. nils can be tricky to deal with.

Comment: They can be. I see many questions on SO where the unexpected behaviour is because a message was sent to `nil` and so the expected thing didn't happen. Always remember to initialise objects

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize it in the `-(id)init`

```
varibs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```